# The vim navigation sweet spot, medium-distance jumps

Tags: vim

In `vim` I often find myself j-stepping by line to go, say, 8 or 10 lines down. For example, if I have a directory open in netrw and the directory I want is 8 lines down I will just <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>. If it is farther down than that I will use a <kbd>/</kbd> search.

Is there any more efficient way for me to do this kind of navigation? I guess I could use <kbd>8</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> but the problem there is that you don't know the exact number of lines so you end up <kbd>j</kbd>-ing and <kbd>k</kbd>-ing anyway. My feeling is there is probably some trick that is better than spamming <kbd>j</kbd>.

Answer (score 8):

```
:set relativenumber
```

has been created to solve that problem.

Comment: Wow, that is VERY useful!

Answer (score 2):

What I find useful is instead of moving the cursor around I move the screen:

```
Ctrl-e - Scroll the screen upwards
Ctrl-y - Scroll the screen downwards
```

As this scrolls the screen then I can easily read the code rather than paginating and then working out where I was.

Then I move the cursor to where I want it on the screen:

```
H   move to top of the screen
M   move to middle of the screen
L   move to bottom of the screen
```

Comment: I have not tried Ctrl-e before. I do use z. a lot.

Comment: I think of H/M/L as High/Middle/Low.

Answer (score 1):

My personal solution to this is to do `5j` or `5k` commands to move 5 lines up or down. I find that it's faster to do repeated `5j` commands, which have become part of my muscle memory, than it is to try to calculate an exact jump.

Of course conditions exist when you want an exact jump, but if you're editing text or code, doing a few `5j` commands followed by individual `j` or `k` commands gets you there pretty fast.